# AWS ecr get-login generates docker login command with an unknown flag

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecs

when I generate the docker login command to my AWS ECR with the following command:

```
aws ecr get-login  --region us-east-2
```

I get an output like:

```
docker login -u AWS -p [bigbass] -e none https://xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

The problem is the `-e` flag that throws an error:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
See 'docker login --help'.
```

I first thought that the problem was a mis configured `aws configure`, as I was using `none` as "Default output format" option. After that I fixed the format option inside `aws configure` but it still happens.

Comment: I think I fixed it by installing a new version of `aws` and including the `--no-include-email` option to the `aws ecr get-login` command

Comment: Already answered in [docker login unknown shorthand flag: 'e'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722341/docker-login-unknown-shorthand-flag-e/44722622).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They not so long ago changed their CLI. It looks like this now:

`get-login
[--registry-ids <value> [<value>...]]
[--include-email | --no-include-email]`

So simply replace `-e none` with `--no-include-email`.

See the corresponding documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html#get-login).