# docker login unknown flag: --no-include-email

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, command-line-interface

I'm trying (and failing) to authenticate docker to AWS ECR. I've generated my AWS token via the AWS CLI `aws ecr get-login` command and have been provided with the following:

`docker login -u AWS -p <token> --no-include-email https://***.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`.

However, when I execute this command, I get `unknown flag : --no-include-email`.

I've done much reading on the subject which all seem to say it's a version problem as `--no-include-email` flag was introduced to replace the deprecated `-e none` flag. I'm running the following versions:
`Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302`,
`AWS CLI 1.16.88`,
`Python 3.6.0`, and
`Windows 7 x64`.

I've even double checked my initial AWS CLI installation by installing AWS CLI via `pip` and checking for an upgraded version with `pip install --user --upgrade awscli`.

I initially had the error described [docker login unknown shorthand flag: 'e'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722341/docker-login-unknown-shorthand-flag-e).

Everything is up-to-date.

It might be worth noting here that I am authenticating with AWS via a standard `credentials file`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ***
aws_secret_access_key = ***
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try the `--no-include-email` on the `aws ecr get-login`, not the `docker` command?

Comment: @stdunbar, `--no-include-email` has no affect on the `aws ecr get-login` command and returns the same `docker login -u AWS -p <token> ...` command.

Comment: Right - the `--no-include-email` is an `aws ecr` option, not a `docker` option.  By default the `get-login` tries to include email but it usually can't find it.

Comment: @stdunbar, the `aws ecr get-login` command returns `docker login -u AWS -p <token> -e none ...` Am I not to execute it entirely as returned? I've removed everything but the `docker login -u AWS -p <token>` part of the command and get some warning about `using --password is insecure, use --password-stdin instead`, then an error during connect `failed to get registry endpoint from daemon (error during connect: Get https://192.168.**.***. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--no-include-email` flag is an AWS CLI flag, not a docker flag. To use it, add it to your `get-login` call:

```sh
$ aws ecr get-login --no-include-email
docker login -u AWS -p ey...V9 https://123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Try comparing with and without the `--no-include-email` flag. You'll notice that using `--no-include-email` omits the `-e none` part of the output. You can copy/paste the given command to login to docker. To save you the copy/paste, login with one command:

```sh
eval "$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)"
```

Comment: Brilliant! The eval command is nice and compact too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me with AWS CLI version 2:
`docker login --username AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password) <aws-ecr-url>`